# Validar el <tab> - TypeError: Cannot set property 'step2' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring

Me estoy integrando a un proyecto antiguo que trabaja con Angular 1.3, Java y Spring.

Lo que intento hacer es que el JavaScript cambie el estado del steps cuando supere la función. Si no es así, que se quede inhabilitado hasta que cumpla las validaciones de la función de mi JS.

Este evento ocurre cuando doy click en "asientos" sin haber llenado algún campo a insertar, como se puede ver en esta imagen:

[image: Imagen descriptiva del problema]

Este es el HTML Completo

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContentConfirma.html">
  <div ng-include="'tpl/confirm/modalDocumentos.html'"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContentClientes.html">
  <div ng-include="'tpl/ventas/modal.clientes.new.html'"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContentProductos.html">
  <div ng-include="'tpl/ventas/modal.productos.new.html'"></div>
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<div class="hbox ">
  <div>
    <form name="formValidate" class="form-horizontal form-validation">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-xs">
        <div class=" panel-body m-b-xs ">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="formValidate.$invalid || !textomsgcodigo" ng-click="crud(1, 2)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-addon" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="{{documentos.iddocumentos==0?'Grabar registro':'Actualizar cambios'}}">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            {{documentos.iddocumentos==0?'Grabar':'Actualizar'}}
          </button>

          <div class="pull-right">
            <a type="button" tooltip-placement="left" tooltip="Click para regresar a la lista" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-addon" ng-click="regresar()">
              <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>{{documentos.iddocumentos==0?'Regresar':'Cancelar'}}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body  panel-default">
          <tabset class="tab-container" ng-init="steps={step1:true, step2:false}">
            <tab heading="Datos del documento" active="steps.step1">
              <div class="panel-body ">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                    <legend class="scheduler-border">Datos del Comprobante de Venta</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Tipo de Comprobante:</label>
                          <select ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-change="seteaCodigo(documentos.idsutipocomprovantepagodocumento)" ng-model="documentos.idsutipocomprovantepagodocumento" ng-options="value.idsutipocomprovantepagodocumento as value.codigosunat +' - '+ value.descripcion for value in sutipocomprovantepagodocumentos">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Código:<i tooltip-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="En el deplegable adjunto puede ver qué código ingresar aquí para encontrar el tipo" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                          <input type="text" valid-number wm-block wm-block-length="1" ng-blur="cargaseridoc(defaults.doc);" ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Código tipo" ng-model="defaults.doc">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Serie:</label> 
                          <select ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-change="seteaCodigoDocumento(documentos.idseriedocumentos)" ng-model="documentos.idseriedocumentos" ng-options="value.idseriedocumentos as value.serie  for value in lsSeries">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Número:</label> <input type="text" ng-blur="validaCodigo()" placeholder="Codigo" ng-model="documentos.codigo" ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div ng-hide="notacredito" class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Comprobante de Referencia:</label> <span ng-hide="notacredito" class="input-group-btn"> 
                          <select class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-required="!notacredito" ng-model="documentos.idreferenncd" ng-options="value.idsutipocomprovantepagodocumento as value.descripcion  for value in sutipocomprovantepagodocumentos | filter:show07| filter:show08">
                      </select>
                      </span>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-hide="notacredito" class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Serie: </label>
                          <span ng-hide="notacredito" class="input-group-btn"> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Serie factura" ng-model="seriefactura" ng-required="!notacredito">
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-hide="notacredito" class="col-sm-3">
                          <label>Número:</label>
                          <input ng-hide="notacredito" type="text" ng-blur="retornaDatanotacredito(seriefactura,codigofactura,0)" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Codigo factura" ng-model="codigofactura" ng-required="!notacredito">
                        </div>
                        <div ng-hide="notacredito" class="col-sm-3">
                          <label ng-hide="notacredito">Motivo para nota de crédito: </label>
                          <div ng-hide="notacredito">
                            <select class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-change="seleccionaTipooperacion(seriefactura,codigofactura)" ng-required="notacredito?fasle:!notadebito?false:true" ng-model="documentos.idsutipooperacion" ng-options="value.idsutipooperacion as value.descripcion  for value in tipotransaccions| filter:showTipoOpComoras|filter:showAnuCompras">
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
                          <label>Fecha de Operación: </label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="documentos.fecharegistrostr" is-open="opened" ng-change="retornaDiasCredito(documentos.idcreditoclientes)" ng-focus="open($event)" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" /> 
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon" ng-click="open($event)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                              </button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label> Moneda: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> 
                          <select ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-disabled="!notacredito" ng-model="documentos.idtipomoneda" ng-change="generaCalculosyAsientosContable();retornaSimbolomoneda(documentos.idtipomoneda)" ng-options="value.idtipomoneda as value.descripcion  for value in tipomonedas">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select> 
                          <span ng-show="myForm.idtipomoneda.$dirty && myForm.idtipomoneda.$invalid" class="help-inline">tipomoneda requerido!</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label>Tipo de Operación: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> 
                          <select class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="!notacredito" ng-model="documentos.tipooperacion" ng-options="value.id as value.name  for value in lstipooperacion">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label>Tipo de  conceptos :<i tooltip-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="Al seleccionar la opción servicio el listado de conceptos seran solo de servicios, caso contrario solo de productos " class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i></label>
                          <select class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-required="true" ng-model="documentos.idtipoconcepto" ng-options="value.id as value.name  for value in lsTipoConcetos">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label> Condición de Pago: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> 
                          <select class="form-control" ng-required="notacredito" ng-disabled="!notacredito" ng-change="seleccionaCredito(documentos.idcondicionespago)" ng-model="documentos.idcondicionespago" ng-options="value.idcondicionespago as value.descripcion  for value in condicionespagos">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select> 
                          <span ng-show="myForm.idcondicionespago.$dirty && myForm.idcondicionespago.$invalid" class="help-inline">idcondicionespago requerido!</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label> Crédito a: </label> 
                          <select ng-disabled="muestracreditos" class="form-control" ng-required="!muestracreditos" ng-model="documentos.idcreditoclientes" ng-change="retornaDiasCredito(documentos.idcreditoclientes)" ng-options="value.idcreditoclientes as value.nombre  for value in creditoclientes">
                            <option>--</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label> Días de Crédito: </label> 
                          <input type="number" ng-disabled="true" ng-required="muestraanticipo" class="form-control" ng-model="documentos.diaspago">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
                          <label> Fecha de Pago: </label> 
                          <input disabled="true" type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="documentos.fechapagostr" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                    <legend class="scheduler-border">Datos del Cliente</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>RUC: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> <input class="form-control  ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="ruc" type="text" required ng-blur="buscaClientePorRuc(clien.ruc)" ng-dblclick="openClientes('lg',1)" ng-model="clien.ruc">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Razón social:</label> 
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="true" class="form-control" ng-model="clien.razonsocial">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Dirección:</label> 
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="true" class="form-control" ng-model="clien.direccion"> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" disabled="true" class="form-control" ng-model="documentos.idcliente">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class=" table table-striped bg-white b-a">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th style="width: 2%">X</th>
                          <th style="width: 10%">Codigo</th>
                          <th style="width: 20%">Producto</th>
                          <th style="width: 15%">Centro Costo</th>
                          <th style="width: 10%">Cantidad</th>
                          <th style="width: 10%">U. Medida</th>
                          <th style="width: 10%">Precio de Venta</th>
                          <th style="width: 8%">Igv.</th>
                          <th style="width: 8%">Sub total</th>
                          <th style="width: 8%">Impuesto</th>
                          <th style="width: 8%">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="d in documentos.lsDetalle">
                          <td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-info text-left" ng-click="deleteItem(d)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></td>
                          <td><input class="form-control" name="dfgdfg" type="text" ng-blur="searchConceptos(d.iddocumentosdetalle,d.codproducto)" ng-dblclick="openProductos('lg',d.iddocumentosdetalle,1,'')" ng-model="d.codproducto"></td>
                          <td><input class="form-control" name="tertret" ng-disabled="d.idconcepto>0?true:false" ng-blur="searchConceptosNombre(d.iddocumentosdetalle,d.producto)" type="text" ng-model="d.producto"></td>
                          <td>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="d.idclasificadorcostos" ng-blur="selectCentroCosto(d.iddocumentosdetalle,d.filtros.conceptos.idconceptos,d.idclasificadorcostos);" ng-disabled="!clasificadorcostoss.length||!notacredito" ng-options="value.idclasificadorcostos as value.nombre  for value in d.dataclasif">

                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-max="notacredito?1000000:d.cantidadfactura" ng-disabled="!notacredito?documentos.idsutipooperacion==12?false:true:false" ng-min="d.idconcepto>0?1:0" ng-required="d.idconcepto>0?true:false" ng-blur="generaCalculosyAsientosContable()" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad" ng-model="d.cantidad">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="d.idunidadmedida" ng-disabled="!notacredito" ng-options="value.idunidadmedida as value.unidad  for value in d.dataunidamedida">
                              <option>--</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-blur="generaCalculosyAsientosContable()" ng-disabled="!notacredito?documentos.idsutipooperacion==12?true:false:false" ng-min="d.idconcepto>0?0.01:0" ng-required="d.idconcepto>0?true:false" ng-max="notacredito?1000000:d.costounitariofactura" placeholder="Ingrese costo unitario" ng-model="d.costounitario">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-blur="generaCalculosyAsientosContable()" ng-disabled="!notacredito" ng-model="d.afectoinafecto" ng-options="value.id as value.name  for value in d.dataafectoinafecto">
                              <option>--</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td>{{simbolo}}{{d.subtotal|currency:''}}</td>
                          <td>{{simbolo}}{{d.impuesto|currency:''}}</td>
                          <td>{{simbolo}}{{d.importe|currency:''}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-hide="!notadebito">
                          <td colspan="4" class="text-left"><a ng-click="agregaNuevo()" ng-hide="!notacredito"><span class="text-primary">Agregar nuevo concepto</span></a></td>
                          <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Totales</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{subtotal|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{totaligv|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{total|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-hide="notadebito">
                          <td colspan="4" class="text-left"><a ng-click="agregaNuevo()" ng-hide="!notacredito"><span class="text-primary">Agregar nuevo concepto</span></a></td>
                          <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Totales</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-change="calculaigvytotal(subtotal,totaligv)" required="!notadebito" placeholder="Ingrese costo unitario" ng-model="subtotal"></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-change="calculaigvytotal(subtotal,totaligv)" required="!notadebito" placeholder="Ingrese costo unitario" ng-model="totaligv"></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-disabled="true" required="!notadebito" placeholder="Ingrese costo unitario" ng-model="total"></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-show="muestraanticipo">
                          <td colspan="3" class="text-left"></td>
                          <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Total de anticipo: </strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{subtotalanticipo|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{totaligvanticipo|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td colspan="1"><strong>{{simbolo}}{{totalanticipo|currency:''}}</strong></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="Asientos" active="steps.step2" ng-click="generaAsientosFin()">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table show-filter="true" export-csv="csv" class="table  table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                  <tr>
                    <td>Cuenta</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Moneda</td>
                    <td>Debe</td>
                    <td>Haber</td>
                    <td>Glosa</td>
                    <td>ruc</td>
                    <td>razonsocial</td>
                    <td>Codigodocumento</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="center" ng-repeat="cat in resultValue=(documentos.lsAsientoscontables)">
                    <td data-title="'Cuenta'" sortable="cuenta">{{cat.cuenta}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Cuenta'" sortable="cuenta">{{cat.namecuenta}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Moneda'" sortable="moneda">{{simbolo}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Debe'" sortable="debe">
                      {{simbolo}}{{cat.debe|currency:''}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Haber'" sortable="haber">{{simbolo}} {{cat.haber|currency:''}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Glosa'" sortable="glosa">{{cat.glosa}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Ruc'" sortable="ruc">{{cat.ruc}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Razonsocial'" sortable="razonsocial">{{cat.razonsocial}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Codigodocumento'" sortable="codigodocumento">{{cat.codigodocumento}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'debe'|currency:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'haber'|currency:''}}</td>
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </tab>
          </tabset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el HTML de las funciones que estoy ocupando.

```
<tabset class="tab-container" ng-init="steps={step1:true, step2:false}"> 
  <tab heading="Datos del documento" active="steps.step1">
    .
    .
    .
  </tab> 
  <tab heading="Asientos" active="steps.step2" ng-click="generaAsientosFin()">
    .
    .
    .
  </tab> 
</tabset>
```

Este es mi función del JS:

```
$scope.generaAsientosFin = function() {
  if ($scope.documentos.idcliente > 00 && $scope.app.settings.periodoselected > 0) {
    if ($scope.documentos.serie != undefined && $scope.documentos.serie.length > 0) {
      $scope.documentos.lsAsientoscontables = [];
      if ($scope.documentos.idsutipooperacion == undefined || $scope.documentos.idsutipooperacion == "") {} else {
        $scope.generaAsientosImpuestoIGV($scope.siigv);
        $scope.cargalosAsientosContableConLaCuentaAsociadaAlConcepto();
        $scope.generaLosAsientosParaLaOperacionDeCompraDesdeLaPlantilla();
        if (!$scope.notacredito) {
          if ($scope.objplancuentadocumento.idplancuenta == undefined && $scope.documentos.idsutipooperacion == undefined) {
            toaster.pop("warning", "", "Por favor verificar el asiento para la nota de credito", 10000, 'trustedHtml');

          } else {
            $scope.objplancuentadocumento.glosa = "ACCD-Por la venta de mercaderia al " + $scope.retornaTipoPago($scope.documentos.idcondicionespago) + " por un total de: " + $scope.simbolo + $filter('currency')(10, "") + "" + " al " + $filter('date')
              ($scope.documentos.fecharegistrostr, "dd-MM-yyyy"),
              $scope.objplancuentadocumento.debe = $scope.total;
            var d = $scope.objplancuentadocumento;
            $scope.documentos.lsAsientoscontables.push(d);
          }
        }

      }
    } else {
      toaster.pop("warning", "", "No se agrego conceptos al documento", 10000, 'trustedHtml');
    }

  } else {
    console.log("Coleccion de Steps ");
    console.log($scope.steps);
    $scope.steps.step2 = false;
    $scope.steps.step1 = true;
    toaster.pop("warning", "", "Por favor seleccione el cliente, o verifique el periodo seleccionado xxx", 10000, 'trustedHtml');
  }
}
```

El error en consola es lo siguiente:

> angular.js:11598 TypeError: Cannot set property 'step2' of undefined
>     at Scope.$scope.generaAsientosFin (ventasController.js?v=1.1.2:1914)
>     at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12336)
>     at angular-touch.js:472
>     at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14388)
>     at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14487)
>     at HTMLLIElement. (angular-touch.js:471)
>     at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4430)
>     at HTMLLIElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4116)

Tomando el código de referencia de otro módulo donde sí funciona esto, lo ejecuto desde consola dándome este resultado. (en las últimas líneas del JS)  obtengo esto:

> Coleccion de Steps 
>   ventasPagosController.js?v=1.1.2:1498 {step1: false, step2: true}

Comment: Seria bueno que crearas un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder analizar mejor el problema. El codigo que muestras esta muy extenso, al menos el HTML (en mi opinion) y es mas dificil encontrar el posible error asi.

Comment: Si bueno tiens razón es extenso pero por eso coloqué debajo el codigo  del html (que dice Este es mi html de las funciones que estoy ocupando. ) y donde estoy  utilizando para llamar a la funcion de mi js